# Inputstream dont read all the file

Tags: java, inputstream

The file that i wrote is 2048 bytes smaller than the original file, was to be a perfect copy.

```
byte [] buffer = new byte[2048];
int readBytes = inputstream.read(buffer, 0, 2048);

while(readBytes !=-1){  
    readBytes = inputstream.read(buffer, 0, 2048); 
    for(int i = 0;i<readBytes;i++){    
        int decimal = buffer[i];
        String binario = conversor.ConverterDecimalToBinario(decimal);
        int decimal1 = conversor.ConverterBinarioToDecimal(binario);
        outputstream.write(decimal1);//-----------------------------------------GRAVAÇÃO
    }//FIM DO FOR
}//FIM DO WHILE
```

Comment: Probably your converter `conversor` is messing you up.  We'd need to see the code.

Comment: Note also that if all you want is a byte-for-byte copy, `Files.copy` will do that for you. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] which can be compiled and tested by others, that shows that the copied file is 2048 bytes smaller than the original.

Answer (score 2):

Up to 2048 bytes are read before the code enters the loop and put to a buffer.

This (up to) 2048 are not dealt with in any way before the buffer is overwritten in the loop with the next (up to)  2048 byte. (see marking in the code)

In essence the first 2048 are skipped.

```
byte [] buffer = new byte[2048]; 
//reads   2048 bytes.
int readBytes = inputstream.read(buffer, 0, 2048);

while(readBytes !=-1){ 
    //reads   2048 bytes - overwrites buffer - furst chunk is skipped! 
    readBytes = inputstream.read(buffer, 0, 2048); 
    for(int i = 0;i<readBytes;i++){    
        int decimal = buffer[i];
        String binario = conversor.ConverterDecimalToBinario(decimal);
        int decimal1 = conversor.ConverterBinarioToDecimal(binario);
        outputstream.write(decimal1);//-----------------------------------------GRAVAÇÃO
    }//FIM DO FOR 
}//FIM DO WHILE
```

For something that won't overwrite - here the next chunk is read at the end of the loop:

```
byte [] buffer = new byte[2048]; 
//reads   2048 bytes.
int readBytes = inputstream.read(buffer, 0, 2048);

while(readBytes !=-1){ 
    for(int i = 0;i<readBytes;i++){    
        int decimal = buffer[i];
        String binario = conversor.ConverterDecimalToBinario(decimal);
        int decimal1 = conversor.ConverterBinarioToDecimal(binario);
        outputstream.write(decimal1);//-----------------------------------------GRAVAÇÃO

    }//FIM DO FOR 
    readBytes = inputstream.read(buffer, 0, 2048);  
}//FIM DO WHILE
```

Or you could do something like this(its a matter of taste if you like this combination of assignment and comparison):

```
byte [] buffer = new byte[2048];
int readBytes;

while(-1 != ( readBytes = inputstream.read(buffer, 0, 2048))){ 
    for(int i = 0;i<readBytes;i++){    
        int decimal = buffer[i];
        String binario = conversor.ConverterDecimalToBinario(decimal);
        int decimal1 = conversor.ConverterBinarioToDecimal(binario);
        outputstream.write(decimal1);//-----------------------------------------GRAVAÇÃO
    }//FIM DO FOR 
}//FIM DO WHILE
```

Comment: more precisely, up to  2048 are skipped, based on the input stream implementation. read does not have to return the full 2048 that were requested.

Comment: How I solution the skiped 2048 first?

Comment: how i dont overwrite? Example?

Comment: see examples in the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!!!!

Comment: now its correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.io.File;

//===========================================================================================================================*/

class conversor {



   /**
    * Converte decimal em binário
    * */
   public static String ConverterDecimalToBinario(int numeroDecimal){
       String binario = "";
       String bin7 = "0000000";
       String bin6 = "000000";
       String bin5 = "00000";            //Completa números binários pequenos, para ficar com 8 bits
       String bin4 = "0000";
       String bin3 = "000";
       String bin2 = "00";
       String bin1 = "0";
       if (numeroDecimal==0){binario = "00000000";}   //Se entra 0 decimal sai 8 zeros(em binário)                                       // Converte decimal em binário
       while(numeroDecimal > 0) {
           binario = (numeroDecimal % 2) + binario;
           numeroDecimal /= 2;
       }
        int stringLength = binario.length();      //tamanho do número sem completar os zero dos 8 bits
        if(stringLength==1){binario = bin7+binario; } 
        if(stringLength==2){binario = bin6+binario; } //concatena os zeros que faltam
        if(stringLength==3){binario = bin5+binario; }         
        if(stringLength==4){binario = bin4+binario; }
        if(stringLength==5){binario = bin3+binario; }
        if(stringLength==6){binario = bin2+binario; }
        if(stringLength==7){binario = bin1+binario; }

return binario;

}

 //-------------------------------------------------
   /**
    * Converte binario em decimal
    * */
   public static int ConverterBinarioToDecimal(String numeroBinario){
       int sum = 0;
       int size = numeroBinario.length();                                        //converte binário em decimal
       char c;
       for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
           c = numeroBinario.charAt(i);
           if (c == '0') continue;
           sum += Math.pow(2, (size-(i+1)));
       }
       return sum;

}}
//----------------------------------------------------FIM DO CONVERSOR---------------------------------------------------


        public class teste {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws java.io.IOException {


int contadorx = 0;
int terminou = 0;


                      InputStream inputstream;  OutputStream outputstream;
                     inputstream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\klebe\\Desktop\\tatuagem.png"));
                     outputstream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\klebe\\Desktop\\deucerto.png");
 //--------------------------------------------TAMANHO DO ARQUIVO--------------------------------------------
                        File f = new File ("C:\\Users\\x\\Desktop\\tatuagem.png");
                        Long tamanhodoarquivo1 = f.length();
                        double tamanhodoarquivo = (double)tamanhodoarquivo1;

                         double conttamanhodoarquivo=0;
//-------------------------------------FIM TAMANHO DO ARQUIVO----------------------------------------
int x = 0;




                                byte [] buffer = new byte[2048];
                                int readBytes = inputstream.read(buffer, 0, 2048);

                                while(readBytes !=-1){  
                                  readBytes = inputstream.read(buffer, 0, 2048); 
                               for(int i = 0;i<readBytes;i++){    
                                int decimal = buffer[i];
                                String binario = conversor.ConverterDecimalToBinario(decimal);
                                int decimal1 = conversor.ConverterBinarioToDecimal(binario);
                             outputstream.write(decimal1);//-----------------------------------------GRAVAÇÃO
}//FIM DO FOR
}//FIM DO WHILE

                                   conttamanhodoarquivo=conttamanhodoarquivo+1;


















//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                    
                   // if (outputstream != null){
                   //  outputstream.close();
                   //  inputstream.close();
                   // }//FIM DO IF

    }//FIM DO PUBLIC STATIC VOID MAIN

}//FIM DA CLASS PRINCIPAL
```

Comment: well thats a nice addition - you could also edit your question and put it there, if you want. Benefit: readers will see it imidiately when looking at your question.